# Cucumber and Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, cucumber, rspec-rails

Can anyone suggest me good source (Easy examples) for cucumber and rspec tutorials (rails 3)???

Edit:

Actually I am looking for free online resources with good examples..

Answer (score 9):

I think the [RSpec Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) is an excellent resource on Cucumber, RSpec and BDD.

Answer (score 5):

Agree - the [RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) provides a wealth of information.  I found getting the flow was a big problem in the learning.  The book gives you the quick intro, then dives into details and by the time you surface your head will be swimming.  It takes a couple of goes of reading the book to get the finer points.

Another great read is a blog post by Sarah Mei called [Outside-In BDD](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2010/05/29/outside-in-bdd/).  This dialog really help to make things gel since it's demonstrating the application of Cucumber/Rspec in the context of the flow a developer would go through.

Then there is the classics such as the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/) from Ryan Bates.  There are a couple of episodes on Cucumber and other tools and the snippets give you a nice overview after you've soaked up the RSpec book.

Answer (score 2):

For Rspec you can read the Michael Hartl book "Rails 3 tutorial" there is a lot of testing examples : [Here the online book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

For cucumber, you can watch teachmetocode screencasts [(website)](http://teachmetocode.com/) . There are good examples using cucumber when building an application from scratch.

Hope it could help!

Answer (score 1):

Screencast walk-throughs can be good sources to grok them

[Peepcode](http://peepcode.com) has a few, like [this one on Cucumber](http://peepcode.com/products/cucumber), which has been updated this year - so I'm assuming it's good for rails 3