# Newbie gotchas in Sarah Mei's "Outside-In BDD: How?!" Cucumber tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I'm trying to learn Cucumber. After [poking around a bit on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357384/765287) I found a link to [this tutorial](http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2010/05/29/outside-in-bdd/). It was very helpful (and I recommend it highly!), but, for a beginner like myself, a couple of the early steps were opaque. I thought I'd explain these two pitfalls here, to spare future Cucumber students the head-scratching they caused me.

The two problems both came up in this section:

> **Starting the fail-fix cycle**
>
> I run it using cucumber features, and it fails on the first line –
>   Given I go to the new book page – because cucumber doesn’t know where
>   the “new book page” is. So I add that to the cucumber paths helper.
>
> ```
> when /the new book page/
>   new_book_path
> ```

I had trouble interpreting this section and running her code.

My first question was: *where do I find the `cucumber paths helper` file*?

Once I figured it out and ran `cucumber features`, I got a syntax error.

My second question was *how do I debug the syntax error that her code raises*?  I've tried to answer these two questions below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Gotcha: *where the heck is the `cucumber paths helper'*?**

First off, she talks about adding a step to the `cucumber paths helper`.  I struggled for a while to figure out where this file was located. I couldn't find anything with a similar name in my app, and google searches didn't yield any useful results. What was going on?

It turns out that I couldn't find the file because it's not automatically generated -- you need to create it yourself. Furthermore, the name of the file is totally arbitrary: it doesn't need to be called `cucumber_paths_helper`. That's why my google searches were fruitless.

For her code snippet to be executed it just needs to be in *some* file living in the `features/support` folder. All of the code in this directory is executed before any cucumber tests are run. The solution? I put her code into a new file at `features/support/manage_books_steps.rb`.

Ok, one down...

**Second Gotcha: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when**

The next problem showed up when I tried to run `cucumber features`. I got this:

```
/Users/dB/myApp/features/support/manage_books_steps.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when
when /the new book page/
    ^ (SyntaxError)
```

For some reason my system couldn't parse this code. I'm not sure why exactly, but I'm guessing that Sarah was using some gem or tool to preprocess her code that I didn't have installed, and she unfortunately didn't go into detail about her gemset in the article. (Maybe she wrote it before cucumber's [training wheels came off](http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off)?) In any case, after consulting some other cucumber tutorials I tried reformatting her snippet like so.

```
When /^I go to the new book page$/ do
  visit new_book_path
end
```

This worked.

After getting past those two little obstacles, the rest of the tutorial was a synch.

Anyway, I hope this helps someone somewhere down the line.  And thanks, Sarah, for a great tutorial.

Edits/comments/corrections are welcome.